# Using onClick listener for switch inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview filled with switches, chronometers, and textviews.  I am populating this recycleview with data from an arraylist which passes a boolean for the switch, a string for the textview, and a long for the time.  Here is my problem, where do I need to put the listener for the switch?  If I put the listener in my adapter class I can't reference the arraylist that stores the values and if I put the listener in my main timeKeeping.java class I can't reference my switches.  I'm new to android dev so I may just be missing something obvious.  I'll provide all the code I've written so far.

Here is my main timeKeeping.java class

```
public class timeKeeping extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<timeTrackCell> timesList = new ArrayList<>();
    //TODO replace empName with data from server
    public String empName = "Zach";
    private RecyclerView rv;
    public timeTrackCellAdapter tAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Button that shows who is logged in
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_keeping2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_temp_profile_image);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String greetingString = "Welcome back, " + empName + "!";
                Snackbar.make(view, greetingString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.timeListTest);
        tAdapter = new timeTrackCellAdapter(timesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager tLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(tLayoutManager);
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv.setAdapter(tAdapter);

        prepareData();

    }
```

Here is the xml file that corresponds to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="I took this out because it contained my name">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:id="@+id/dateSelect"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-110dp"
            android:translationY="-35dp"
            ></DatePicker>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_time_keeping2" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/timeListTest"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="55dp"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my timeKeepingCell.java class that stitches my main class and my adapter together

```
    public class timeTrackCell {
        private boolean switchPosition;
        private long chronometerTime;
        private String jobString;

        public timeTrackCell(boolean switchPosition, long chronometerTime, String jobString){
            this.switchPosition = switchPosition;
            this.chronometerTime = chronometerTime;
            this.jobString = jobString;
        }
        //sets
        public void setSwitchPosition(boolean switchPosition){
            this.switchPosition = switchPosition;
        }
        public void setChronometerTime(long chronometerTime){
            this.chronometerTime = chronometerTime;
        }
        public void setJobString(String jobString){
            this.jobString = jobString;
        }
        //gets
        public boolean getSwitchPosition(){
            return switchPosition;
        }
        public long getChronometerTime(){
            return chronometerTime;
        }
        public String getJobString(){
            return jobString;
        }


    }
```

Here is my timeTrackCellAdapter.java class which is my adapter

```
public class timeTrackCellAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<timeTrackCellAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<timeTrackCell> jobDataList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView jobDesc;
        public Switch jobSwitch;
        public Chronometer jobTime;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {

            super(view);
            jobDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondaryRowText);
            jobSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.timeSwitch);
            jobTime = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.timeTracker);
        }


    }

    public timeTrackCellAdapter(List<timeTrackCell> jobDataList) {
        this.jobDataList = jobDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        timeTrackCell tView = jobDataList.get(position);
        holder.jobDesc.setText(tView.getJobString());
        holder.jobSwitch.setChecked(tView.getSwitchPosition());
        long elapsedRealtimeOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - tView.getChronometerTime();
        holder.jobTime.setBase(elapsedRealtimeOffset);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobDataList.size();
    }

}
```

And here is the xml file for the custom cell I built

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="140px"
    >
    <!--140px Seems to be the right height for 7 cells per page-->
    <!-- Block for custom listview items -->
    <Chronometer
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timeTracker"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </Chronometer>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondaryRowText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeTracker"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingTop="30px"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timeSwitch"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        >
    </Switch>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `Switch` you need to implement [setOnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) and not `onClickListener`

The following code can go inside `onBindViewHolder` if you want do something different for each switch in the RecyclerView or inside the `ViewHolder` if it's independent

```
jobSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // do something, the isChecked param will be
        // true if the switch is in the On position
    }
});
```